# jquery autocomplete not sticking to the element from which its called

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a div inside my webpage that is set as `draggable` with jquery. Inside it I load a webpage with the `.load()` function and there are textboxes which use the jquery autocomplete function.

The moment I start typing and the dropdown appears, if I drag the div to move it on a side, the dropdown will remain in the same position but the div moves.

Is there any option to force the dropdown to bind itself to the textbox so that if the `div` is moved the dropdown will follow?

Comment: How abt creating a jsfiddle?

Comment: The dropdown of most autocompletes is a dynamically created, reused, floating div (or other element), usually with an *absolute position* based on the parent control position at click time. You need to adjust the position of the dynamic element based on the movement of your div (or close the dropdown on drag start).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KaLQK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained you must either:

1. Adjust the autocomplete menu position while dragging your div
2. Or close the autocomplete when dragging start

### 1. Adjust the autocomplete menu position while dragging

This can be easily done by calling [jquery-ui .position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) while [dragging](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) :

```
$( "#drag" ).draggable({
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        $('.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').position({
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left bottom',
            of: '#tbox'
        });
    }
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KaLQK/2/)</kbd>

- +: search results stay visible and you don't have to perform search again (or at least redisplay results) when dragging stop
- -: many calls to jquery-ui position because the drag event will be raised many times. Plus your user have to click outside your draggable div to close the autocomplete menu

### 2. Close the autocomplete when dragging start

As you click on your div to drag, it is quite common to unfocus the input (common behaviour when you click outside an input). So just perform this when dragging start :

```
$( "#drag" )
    .draggable({
        start: function(e, ui) {
            // unfocus input will close the autocomplete menu
            // you can also call $( "#tbox" ).autocomplete('close');
            // but your input will still have focus and you will
            // need to use the down arrow key to redisplay autocomplete results
            // or perform another keypress
            $( "#tbox" ).blur();
        }
    });
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KaLQK/3/)</kbd>

- +: just one `.blur()` when dragging start. Common behaviour for end user
- -: user have to select the input again and press a key (like down arrow key) to display results. Another search has to be done (can be annoying if you use remote data for your autocomplete field)

Another solution would be to use the 2nd scenario and to add a listener to the [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) draggable event, in which you redisplay results (if there are results)